# Approach: Using Vue SPA/ PWA with SSR?

Tags: vuejs2, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am developing a SPA PWA similar in nature to Stack Overflow and Twitter and have reached a point I need to figure out my strategy with managing user experience with SEO.

A site like StackOverflow needs to rank well in google, and a site like Twitter needs to be shareable (renderable) on social media platforms. Both of these issues have led me to consider SSR.

However from a performance perspective, while I know the initial page loads faster with SSR, I have fallen in love with the native feel of my app with its quick load times between internal pages which I do not want to loose in a switch to SSR.

From what I have gathered, prerendering isn't an option on a site with a good deal of user generated content and/ or database interaction. So that approach seems to be out.

**My Questions:**

1. Would using a mixed SSR approach be the proper approach here: sending initial load as SSR and all subsequent loads through SPA JavaScript?
2. Perhaps using SSR only on detailed page views would be better, and populate the rest of the app (user feed, etc.) as SPA CSR since the only pages that need to rank or be sharable are the user generated pages. Is this possible/ advisable?
3. If #1 is a good choice, would google crawler receive SSR content when it follows internal links/ site map, or just the first page like a user would be served?
4. My approach must also be advisable for a Progressive web app which will generate all content via Firestore database. Would this impact my approach? The very nature of SSR seems to be counter productive to what PWAs set out to accomplish. Not to mention how Firestore binded content on SSR will work.

Also if you know of any good tutorials on these things please let me know. There seems to be little information on combining Vue/ SPA/ SSR/ PWA strategy on a use case such as Stackoverflow type site.

Comment: You should check out nuxt.js and https://forum.vuejs.org/ is a much better medium for this type of question.

Comment: @Austio Thanks for recommending the vue forum. I wasn't sure if this would be ok for SO or not. I will repost Q there and update with link here once account is accepted by mods there.Thanks for advice!

Comment: Im currently making a SSR Vue Website as a PWA + Firestore as Backend. Basicly Nuxt for example allows you to fetch the firestore content on the Rendering so you serve a SSRendered page even if it comes from your firestore. I also had no complications combining it with the benefits of a PWA.

Comment: To any future viewers: I have gotten further advice to this question from the VueJS forum @Austio recommended at: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/approach-using-vue-spa-pwa-with-ssr/47785